# Inserting a rectangle image inside a hexagon image using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an image of a hexagon, and another image in the shape of a rectangle.  I want to put the rectangle image inside the hexagon shaped image.  I know this can be done using CSS, but the shape of my hexagon is special.  I have tried creating multiple divs embedded in one another and styling the position to relative and absolute, respectfully, but it doesn't work.  Basically, how to I insert an oddly shaped image inside another oddly shaped image?  It seems like a simple solution, but I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would have tried would be to put the hexagon image in a parent div, set its position to either relative or absolute, then put your square image in a div nested into the hexagon image's div. Then position that absolutely to where you want it.

That should work, but it sounds like you already tried that. What is it doing?

Comment: It's showing the child div(rectangle) on top of the parent div(hexagon), both in the original shapes, even though overflow is set to hidden.